# Sequelize findOne not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Following function should fetch one record from model *Servers* where field 'game' is '5'

```
Servers.findOne({ where: { game : '5' } }).then(function(s){
            fetched(s);
    });
```

1. **Expected query**

   > SELECT ... **WHERE 'game' =  '5'**
2. **Query generated and executed by sequelize**

   > Executing (default): SELECT `id` AS `id`, `address` AS `address`, `port` AS `port`, `game` AS `game`, `priority` AS `priority`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Servers` AS `Servers` **WHERE 1=1** LIMIT 1;

Server.js (model file)

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){ 
  return sequelize.define("Servers", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
      field: "id",             
      autoIncrement: !0,       
      primaryKey: !0
    },
    address: {               
      type: DataTypes.STRING,  
      field: "address"      
    },
    port: {                
      type: DataTypes.STRING,  
      field: "port"       
    },
    game: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: "game"
    },
    priority: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'priority'
    }
  }, 
  {
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    classMethods:{

      },
    instanceMethods:{

    }

  });
};
```

What am i missing here? I

Comment: can you post your model  file?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg, Added model file.

Comment: Can you try this.  `Servers.findOne({ where: { game : 5 } }).then(function(s){
            fetched(s);
    });` . I am not sure how much this will help. I removed single quote from the condition.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg not working.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. I'm using exactly the same model file and the query was `SELECT "id", "address", "port", "game", "priority", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Servers" AS "Servers" WHERE "Servers"."game" = 5 LIMIT 1`.